# Xero API Organization call return obfuscated TaxNumber

Tags: xero-api

Our application calls the https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Organisation endpoint, returning details about authorized 3rd party organization's Xero accounts. 
Most of our clients are from New Zealand and we use the Organization 'TaxNumber'.  
However I have an Australian customer who's TaxNumber is coming back obfuscated - with the correct number in a different field called 'RegistrationNumber'. 
Is this expected? The customer showed me their financial settings screen and it does appear to have a correct value, rather than "xxxxxxxx536".

Answer (score 0):

From having a look at the endpoint it looks like we have an explicit check to mask the TaxNumber on the organisation endpoint for Australian orgs.
I don't know the exact reasons for this but I would say it's just compliance related to different rules about how sensitive that data is in different jurisdictions.

Disclosure: I am a developer at Xero

Comment: Ok thanks for letting me know.